# Get values from 2 different table but shows only 1 table data

Tags: sql, join, group-by, inner-join

Hie
It might be unclear my query in the title,Let me clear you in the description.
I have 2 tables in the DB with name of 'ABC' and 'XYZ'.

ABC table

## | ID   | name | phone | gender |

1        | dave       | 23423     | Male 
  2        |  rayman   | 987887   | female
3        | shawn    | 6237267 | male

XYZ table

## | ID   | user-id   | blood-group   | rh-factor  |

1         |        3          |          AB                  |    +     
2        |        1           |
                                       B                   |       - 
As you seen above there are two table, now I want result that user whose gender is Male, blood-group is B and rh-factor is negative.
but output should be

## | ID   | name | phone | gender |

1        | dave       | 23423     | Male

hope you understand what I mean.I don't know there should be user GROUP BY or what.
thanks in advance.

Comment: select a.* from abc a Inner join xyz b on a.id = b.userId where b.bood_group = b and b.rh-factor = - ;

Comment: Please put your current code in your question.

Comment: Thankyou for your response Salman. But I have moved the column from table 1 to  table 2.
thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* FROM ABC a JOIN XYZ b ON a.ID=b.ID
WHERE b.Bloodgroup='B' AND a.gender='Male' and b.rh_factor='-'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!..

select abc.id,abc.name,abc.phone,abc.gender from abc inner join xyz
on abc.id = xyz.user-id where abc.gender = 'male' and xyz.blood-group = 'b' and xyz.rh-factor='-'

Regards.
SK

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT a.* FROM ABC a INNER JOIN XYZ b ON a.ID = b.`user-id`
WHERE  b.bood_group = 'B' and b.rh-factor = '-'
```

Use *backtick(`)* if your column has hyphen in it like it in your user-id

Comment: Hie Akash
this is the url
http://wellspringinfotech.com/eggdonor/
send me your Email
I will send you what I want exactly.

Comment: It is better to include description in your post